# Handler definition on sensu client

Tags: sensu

Is it possible to send metrics from client directly to graphite bypassing server? For this I've defined handler on client and point handler to udp socket with graphite. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The client is not configured to make use of handlers. You could do this by having the check itself ship metrics over TCP before exiting, but that is not really a supported approach from Sensu. You're probably better off using something like [Telegraf](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf) for shipping to Graphite directly from clients.

Answer (score 0):

Due to Sensu's decoupled design, it's not possible to bypass the Sensu Server, as the connections work like so:

sensu-client --> rabbitmq(or whatever you're using for your transport mechanism) --> sensu-server

Vase is correct in that you'll have to use something else to ship metrics to Graphite, or something similar. It's also worth noting that specifying a handler on a client definition will not work. The handler will have to be specified in the check, as handlers are dealt with on the sensu-server side. For a better understanding of the Sensu flow, I'd recommend taking a look at the free training done during the fall: http://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLqLtpBjHqwC-4o7HLtK3MM2V_GdtSh-Dw . If you have any questions after watching that, I'd head over to the Sensu community slack channel at slack.sensu.io.